# if block and with block confusion

Tags: vba, excel

I had this code working, then tried to add a loop, to work over several sheets, which I failed, so tried to return to the original version, and now i can't get that working either.
I have tried just about evere iteration i can see of where to put the with/end with and if/end if but now i am lost.
Can anyone see what i have done wrong?

```
Sub Applyfilter()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim LastRowColA As Long
  Dim sCell As Range, lstCell As Range, filterRng As Range
  Dim i As Integer

  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OPT 1 Total")

  With ws
    Set sCell = .Cells.Find(What:="WFE", LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If Not sCell Is Nothing Then
       Set lstCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, sCell.Column).End(xlUp)

       If lstCell.Row > 1 Then
         'Debug.Print sCell, lstCell
  End With

  Range("A1").Select
  Selection.End(xlToRight).Select ' select all cols from A to last populated
  Selection.AutoFilter
  ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear

  ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
     Range(sCell, lstCell), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption _
     :=xlSortNormal

  With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort
     .Header = xlYes
     .MatchCase = False
     .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
     .SortMethod = xlPinYin
     .Apply
  End With

  End If

  End If

  Set filterRng = Range("A2").CurrentRegion
  i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("WFE", Range("A1:AZ1"), 0)

  'Set filter to only look for WFE greater than 0.5
  filterRng.AutoFilter Field:=i, Criteria1:=">=0.5" _
     , Operator:=xlAnd

  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your question is very vague... what specifically is not working?

Comment: For starters, your `End If`'s are out of place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get your original code back up and running.  You just had your `End With` and `End If`'s a bit out of order.

```
Sub Applyfilter()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim LastRowColA As Long
  Dim sCell As Range, lstCell As Range, filterRng As Range
  Dim i As Integer

  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OPT 1 Total")

  With ws
    Set sCell = .Cells.Find(What:="WFE", LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If Not sCell Is Nothing Then
      Set lstCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, sCell.Column).End(xlUp)

      If lstCell.Row > 1 Then
            'Debug.Print sCell, lstCell
      End If

      Range("A1").Select
      Selection.End(xlToRight).Select ' select all cols from A to last populated
      Selection.AutoFilter
      ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear

      ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
         Range(sCell, lstCell), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption _
         :=xlSortNormal

    End If
  End With

  With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort
     .Header = xlYes
     .MatchCase = False
     .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
     .SortMethod = xlPinYin
     .Apply
  End With

  Set filterRng = Range("A2").CurrentRegion
  i = Application.Match("WFE", Range("A1:AZ1"), 0)

  'Set filter to only look for WFE greater than 0.5
  filterRng.AutoFilter Field:=i, Criteria1:=">=0.5" _
     , Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

---

Now, to loop through each sheet try wrapping your code with this block: *(change sheet names to desired sheets to loop through)*

```
For Each ws In Sheets(Array("OPT 1 Total", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"))
   'your code to loop here
Next
```

---

Full code: *(change sheet names to desired sheets to loop through)*

```
Sub ApplyfilterLoop()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRowColA As Long
    Dim sCell As Range, lstCell As Range, filterRng As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    For Each ws In Sheets(Array("OPT 1 Total", "Sheet2"))
        With ws
          Set sCell = .Cells.Find(What:="WFE", LookAt:=xlWhole)

          If Not sCell Is Nothing Then
            Set lstCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, sCell.Column).End(xlUp)

            If lstCell.Row > 1 Then
                  'Debug.Print sCell, lstCell
            End If

            ws.Activate
            ws.Range("A1").Select
            Selection.End(xlToRight).Select ' select all cols from A to last populated
            Selection.AutoFilter
            ws.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear

            ws.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
               Range(sCell, lstCell), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption _
               :=xlSortNormal

          End If
        End With

        With ws.AutoFilter.Sort
           .Header = xlYes
           .MatchCase = False
           .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
           .SortMethod = xlPinYin
           .Apply
        End With

        Set filterRng = ws.Range("A2").CurrentRegion
        i = Application.Match("WFE", ws.Range("A1:AZ1"), 0)

        'Set filter to only look for WFE greater than 0.5
        filterRng.AutoFilter Field:=i, Criteria1:=">=0.5", Operator:=xlAnd
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks!!!!! the original version works, but the loop doesn't? it gets stuck at "ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear" err91 object variable or with block not set. Instead of ActiveSheet i tries to make it"ws.", but that didn't work, any ideas

Comment: Ahhh... I should have caught that.  You were on the right tract with replacing the ws.  See my edit.  I tested it on a simple example.

Comment: thanks that works fine. If i wanted to replace the array with something more dynamic eg If ws.Name Like "*OPT* Total" Then... i get an error. I put the End If, at the end just before the Next, and also tried after it, but i get different errors. Can i not do it this way?

Comment: Not sure I follow what your attempting to do, may I suggest accepting this as answered and then posting a new question with your current code and what errors you are seeing?  Regards